# Indoor map and wayfinding - Mazemap

Tags: android, google-maps, indoor-positioning-system, google-indoor-maps

I am planning to use  [Mazemap](https://www.mazemap.com)  API to create an Android app for indoor map and wayfinding for my university. The university is 140,000 square meters and I'm afraid I cant afford to pay if I use Mazemap.

What are the pros and cons of using Mazemap for this kind of project? Are there any **free** alternatives for Mazemap?

**Note: I am from Philippines, Google Indoor Maps is not supported.**

Comment: Interesting question but I'm affraid it's off toppic.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Mazemap is a mapping platform rather than indoor positioning. i.e. it is not to be used for indoor navigation with mobile phone (they do have partners that do that for additional charge) but for the part of mapping an area into a set of routes and points of interest for the purpose of providing a web/mobile API to present those maps and show the routes between 2 points etc.
An alternative for that can be Micello (also not free), and to this point im not aware of any free tools that do that efficiently.
what you can try is use OSM indoor [module](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Indoor_Mapping) for that. I never did that since it seemed like a lot of work but seems that its (google indoorOSM).

Disclaimer: Im the founder of [Shimeba](http://shimeba.com) - we do apps for venues with pedestrian navigation including all the indoor/outdoor mapping needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use OSM maps, there is free cross platform map editor called JOSM. OSM format is quite simple -- it's just xml, so it will be easy to use in any kind of apps.